# Why are there comma's in my output when I use .map in a template literal?

Tags: javascript

I have variable and loop inside like this:

```js
var htmlmask = `
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>種類</td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-element maskselectop">
                <select class="form-element">
                    ${masktypes.map((masktype, i)=>{
                        let option = '';
                        return option = `<option value="${masktype}" ${(i === 0) ? 'selected' : ''}>${masktype}</option>`;
                    })}
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>`;

$('body').html(htmlmask);
```

Can you tell me why the `comma` appears between `option` after return?

[image]

What wrong with my syntax?

Comment: When you stringify an array, it becomes to a comma separated list of the values.

Comment: @Teemu so solution should be?

Comment: You didn't ask for a solution, you only asked "_why_" ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected comma using map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812160/unexpected-comma-using-map)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function returns a new array. And when you concatenate an array to a string, the array is converted into a string as well. And when an array is converted to a string, it is separated by comma's.

```js
const arr = ['<a>', '<b>'];

console.log(arr.toString()); // <a>,<b>
```

I would use the [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function to reduce the array into a single string.

```
masktypes.reduce((acc, masktype, i) => 
    acc + `<option value="${masktype}" ${(i === 0) ? 'selected' : ''}>${masktype}</option>`, '')
```

So the complete code would become:

```js
const masktypes = ["1", "2"];

var htmlmask = `
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>種類</td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-element maskselectop">
                    <select class="form-element">
                        ${masktypes.reduce((acc, masktype, i) => 
                            acc + `<option value="${masktype}" ${(i === 0) ? 'selected' : ''}>${masktype}</option>`, '')}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>`;

$('body').html(htmlmask);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Small note, I intended to delete this answer after I found a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812160/unexpected-comma-using-map) so I could answer it there instead. (To keep all the useful information in one place.) Unfortunately due to this answer being accepted, I cannot delete it.

Answer (score 9):

It is making your array of elements as strings. Use

```
<select class="form-element">
    ${masktypes.map((masktype, i)=>{
        let option = '';
        return option = `<option value="${masktype}" ${(i === 0) ? 'selected' : ''}>${masktype}</option>`;
    }).join("")}
</select>
```

Just add `.join("")` and it would join without the commas.